# RSACng setting salt value

Tags: .net, cryptography, cng

I have official test vectors (FIPS 186-4 https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/digital-signatures#rsavs, `SigGenPSS_186-3.txt`) for PSS, I need to add a specific salt to test PSS. Is there any way I could add custom salt to `RSACng`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

CNG doesn’t allow it, so `RSACng` can’t allow it, either.

[NCryptSignHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptsignhash) takes a [BCRYPT_PSS_PADDING_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-_bcrypt_pss_padding_info), which only asks how many bytes to use for a salt, not what the bytes should be.

`RSACng` doesn’t even expose that, sticking with the “as many as the size of the hash algorithm” recommendation (as stated in the [RSASignaturePadding.Pss](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsasignaturepadding.pss) property documentation).